# A question regarding the joint density of two random variables

Tags: probability

Please take a look at my working. I would like to know if it is correct. Thank you for your time.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ and calculate $P(X\lt Y)$.

**Attempt**

The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is as follows.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu y} & \text{ if } x \ge 0, y \ge 0, \\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise }.
\end{cases}$$

We have $$P(X\lt Y)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \mu e^{-\mu y}dx dy$$

Then

$$\lambda \mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y}e^{-(\lambda x + \mu y)}dx dy=\lambda \mu \int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{e^{-(\lambda x + \mu y)}}{-\lambda}\right]_{0}^{y} dy$$

Continuing, we have

$$ \dfrac{\lambda \mu}{-\lambda} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-(\lambda + \mu )y}-e^{-\mu y}\right)dy=-\mu \left [ \dfrac{e^{-(\lambda + \mu )y}}{-(\lambda + \mu)} - \dfrac{e^{-\mu y}}{(-\mu)} \right]_{0}^{\infty}=\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}.$$

Comment: It is all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is correct.  I'd have found your working slightly easier to follow if you had made it clearer that you were doing the x-integration first, e.g. you could have written something like

$$
\lambda \mu \int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{e^{-(\lambda x + \mu y)}}{-\lambda}\right]_{x=0}^{x=y} dy
$$

but no big deal!